# jquery validation engine format error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get the validation engine to return only the custom error message. If I do something as simple as:

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
```

and then leave the email input blank in my form, I receive validation saying "*This field is required" AND "*Invalid email address". I only want to display "*Invalid email address". The demo shows that this is possible ([validation demo](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoRegExp.html#)) but the source code for the demo looks like mine, yet the demo properly displays "*Invalid email address" only!

Answer (score 0):

On Validation Demo page, it shows only one message because they have already provided some value in the input box. Try to remove the value from the field and hit submit. It will display 2 message there too.